# Java reserved words as identifiers

Tags: java

this is my first post here. I'm taking my first class in Java and I have come across a question which I believe is a trick question. I know that reserved words can't be used as identifiers and identifiers are only supposed to use upper/lowercase letters, 0-9, $, and _. long is a reserved word, but would using LONG be ok since Java is case sensitive? I have looked all over google for the answer for this. I could not find an answer on stack overflow so sorry if this is answered elsewhere on the forum!

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have figured out by yourself that reserve words are also case sensitive when you say that Java is case sensitive.

Using `LONG` as identifier would not cause any problem for the Java compiler, but the problem is variable name LONG may not mean much and might not contribute to a readable code

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will allow you to use LONG as an identifier.

Your fellow programmers, however, will try to hold you back.

Comment: They will do more than that ;)